# Are you using CC libraries?

Tags: creative-cloud

Maybe a dumb question, but I just wanted to know if Adobe's CC Libraries are actually being used by professionals, or whether they are just something Adobe is trying to force on everybody but isn't being used.

If you use them, what do you use them for?
Does it make sense to put everything in there, or only certain types of assets, like colours and the likes.

I hope I am not asking to broad of a question here, but I am really confused as to whether I should use them or not. Every time I do, I kind of get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use them for different clients. So I'd have logos, colours and any elements belonging to that client in a seperate library. It makes it really quick to create new work for them rather than getting assets from old files.

The assets in the Adobe market are really useful too. If I'm in a hurry and need a quick background that's often where I'll head. I've then got them to use later too.

The fact that they sync between my laptop and desktop is really handy too

Answer (score 0):

They're extremely handy for teams or if you're working on multiple computers. If you work for yourself and only on computer the most important is that you can work fast and that your assets are backed up.

Comment: You are right. I have recently started to use them for a team project, too. Especially for smaller assets that sync fast they are great :)